# Not drawing image/bitmap from correct drawable folder on canvas

Tags: android, android-layout

I am new to android, and I'm trying to make a game that draws some image/bitmap. I have separate folders for drawable, however the emulator for tablet(wxga) is drawing the bitmap from drawable-mdpi even though I have proper images in drawable-xhdpi folder. What can the issue be? It would be great if you can point in the right direction.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you post your AndroidManifest.xml file?

Might be supports-screen tag is missing in it.

Comment: I have <supports-screens android:anyDensity="true" /> in manifest file

Answer (score 0):

The emulator is doing the correct thing.
Have you read the official [docs?](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)

wxga is 1280×768 pixels, combined with a 10 inch screen that is actually mdpi. You need to specifcy a smaller screen size to increase the dpi.

On a side note: Most large android tablets have in fact mdpi resolution. But be careful: the Samsung Galaxy 10.1 Tab reports that it has hdpi even though the screen is technically mdpi.